# Porting Qt Program to Windows

Tags: c++, qt-creator, linker-errors, porting, qt5

I am attempting to port a Qt application from Linux to Windows. I do my development in Linux with just qmake in terminal and .pro files.

When I import the project into QtCreator it asks for paths on where to place debug and release output. What is the purpose of this? Can I configure my .pro file to give it this information straight away?

My second questions is when the project has been imported QtCreator creates another file named project.pro.user. What is the purpose of this?

Third question is once I have successfully imported the project and go to compile I get the following linking error 'LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0\msvc2010\lib\Qt5Widgets500.lib''. I have checked and the file it is after is not there but there is a 'Qt5Widgets' lib file.

I am running this on Windows XP using Qt 5.

Thanks in advance.

clock.pro

```
CONFIG = qt \
         debug

QT += widgets

include(include/headers.pro)
include(src/sources.pro)

DEPENDPATH += include
INCLUDEPATH += include
VPATH += src
DESTDIR = bin
MOC_DIR = tmp
OBJECTS_DIR = tmp
QMAKE_DISTCLEAN = -r bin tmp

TEMPLATE = app

TARGET = Clock
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first question: in an IDE like QtCreator you can have several configurations (with different compiler options). Default configurations are Debug and Release. Each configuration is compiled into a separate directory.

For the second question: There are (personal/local) project settings that one usually wants to keep for oneself and does not want to share with others, e.g. one's current debugging settings like command line parameters for starting the program. These settings are kept in a separate project file, which is usually not committed to a version control system.

For the third question: This might be a bug / misconfiguration for Qt5. I have no experience with this yet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah I have given up on Qt5 4.8 is much more reliable. For the second question this is helpful however I noticed that if I make changes to my .pro file they will not take effect unless I unload the project and import it again deleting the user data.

Comment: @Thomas Once you have loaded your project into an IDE (like QtCreator) you should manage all project settings there. Of course, the IDE can only regard changes to your .pro file if it reloads it ... Visual Studio has the feature of automatically detecting if the project file of a loaded project was changed externally and prompts you if it shall reload the project.